# google translator plugin for different languages

Tags: feature-request, languages

I see some a lot of Spanish (and other languages) questions. is it possible to provide a Google translator plug-in for those or all question? Or provide it through out Ask Ubuntu (Question answer and comment)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Related](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1506/what-to-do-with-non-english-questions-or-answers).

My opinion is no.  We should not do this.  It would in effect encourage splintering the site in to a bunch of different languages.

Questions and answers are supposed to be English.  Making a plug-in or incorporating one would just encourage people to do what they're already asked not to do.

That being said, a user-script might be a nice way to do it without making it official/accepted.

Comment: +1 for the user script idea. And it could even allow the user to select between different online translation services (as Google Translator is really one among many, or at least several...).