# How to prevent answers and comments to question in non-english before they're translated?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Which mechanisms exist to prevent excluding users from questions and the discussion on non-english questions. Currently it's possible that users discuss and answer in non-english and receive credit for it. It is highly unlikely that someone who asked in non-english and received a helpful answer (in english or non-english) will translate the question or eventually support translating the answer.

It's clear for me [how to deal with non-english questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6853/does-it-make-sense-to-flag-non-english-questions) from pov of the site, just want to shed some light on this issue.

Won't it make sense to introduce a new lock mode (like "off-topic", "protected", etc.) for questions until they're translated?

Answer (score 11):

Most of these untranslated questions get a translation rather quickly. By the time 5 people voted on it to be closed it probably will be translated anyways. Then it would take several re-open votes or a moderator to re-open it. Too much administrative work for something that seems to solve itself within a few minutes of it being posted.

Besides that the ...

> Unclear
>
> What you're asking Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

basically covers this. It is a close vote asking for a better worded question. Fits the bill for translations.