# AskUbuntu and Meta AskUbuntu in other languages?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, stackexchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any plans for localized Ask Ubuntu instances?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/533/are-there-any-plans-for-localized-ask-ubuntu-instances)

If not question, or proposed assertion. But what we do know is that I have very hard every time you ask a question, translated into google or some other translator. As I could help or could be done?