# Can I suggest a Spanish askubuntu

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any plans for localized Ask Ubuntu instances?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/533/are-there-any-plans-for-localized-ask-ubuntu-instances)

Sometimes is easier to make a question or explain one in your own lenguage... It is possible to have an "Que Ubuntu?"

So this si more like a how-to deal

- Where can I suggest this?
- What haveto do to get this?
- Do I have to get more reputation to do this?