# Is there analog of askubuntu on russian?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any plans for localized Ask Ubuntu instances?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/533/are-there-any-plans-for-localized-ask-ubuntu-instances)

I'm looking for good resource similar to Ask Ubuntu on Russian. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 2):

There's a service, similar to askubuntu, but for russian users: http://rubuntu.com
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I was looking for