# Can't english, is there a german Supporter here?

Tags: discussion

There are many people who can not speak English. 
Why we are obliged to write in English?
Are there any German supporter here on Askubuntu?
That's just sad: (

Comment: Yes, we do have people (e.g. me) who speak German but this site is being read by the whole world. We therefore decided to speak English only here. We will however help you with your posts to edit them for proper English. Therefore you could even use Google translate to post. (German: wenn Du Schwierigkeiten hast, kannst Du auch den Google Übersetzer bemühen, wir versuchen dann mit einem Edit ein gutes Englisch zu generieren).

Comment: related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/533/are-there-any-plans-for-localized-ask-ubuntu-instances and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1506/what-to-do-with-non-english-questions-or-answers

Comment: Do we put on hold (or close) questions given in another language (than English)? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/349208/instalacion-manual

Comment: Related: The german local community at [ubuntuusers.de](http://ubuntuusers.de) is fantastic! They have one of the best Wikis (often better than the official ubuntu wiki) and they're all lovely people :)

Comment: I'm a user in ubuntuusers.de. but there not all problems are solved